# Can you see I'm raising my hand

Tags: grammar

An online classroom just released a new version. Some of the teachers there need to get familiar with the new system.

There is a button called "raise hand", which is in grey background color by default, as shown below.

[image: Icon depicting a raised hand]

When I click the button, it turns blue and keep blue until I click it again.

[image: Same icon with reversed colours]

I am helping one of them with raising hand feature. I click "raising hand" button in my end and check if the teacher on the other end can see it.

> Can you see I'm raising my hand?

Is the sentence clear, grammatically correct and polite?

Comment: Yes - but if the teacher sees that your hand is already raised - rather than being raised - you might ask: **Can you see my raised hand?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your meaning slightly clearer I would normally use something along the lines of:

`Can you see that I'm "raising my hand"?`

The use of quotes emphasises that you don't mean it literally, but otherwise the phrase is fine in most cases. (This, and most things, can be considered impolite if the context is too rushed/demanding.)